# The two time difference calculation gives error when the difference is 9 in hours, minutes or seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

Good morning, everyone,

I have a very curious problem. I have a form and a javascript script to calculate the difference between an entry time and an exit time.

If for example I set the following times:

IN: 09:09:59
OUT: 16:13:14

It results in 06:13:15 which is correct.

The problem is when there is a difference of 9 in hour, minute or second, that's when you don't do the calculations well or for some reason you don't show the sum in the "result" box.
sec: 01 to 10
min: 01 to 10
Hours: 01 to 10

examples to see it clearly would be:

FAILURE OF THE HOUR:
IN: 09:59:59
OUT: 19:13:14
RESULT: ERROR

FAILURE IN MINUTES:
IN: 09:59:59
OUT: 20:09:14
RESULT: ERROR

SECOND FAULT
IN: 09:59:00
OUT: 20:10:09
RESULT: ERROR

When the difference is 9 in any one of them it doesn't show up, I'm super confused.

The code I have to do the calculations is..:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script>
window.onchange = function () {
    var start = document.getElementById("tcin").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("tcout").value;

    function diff(start, end) {
        start = start.split(":");
        end = end.split(":");
        var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], start[2] ? start[2] : 0, 0);
        var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], end[2] ? end[2] : 0, 0);

        //para que el cálculo funcione si la hora final se cruza al día siguiente. Por ejemplo. 11pm a 2am
        if (endDate.getTime() < startDate.getTime()) {
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
        }

        var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

        var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
        diff -= minutes * 1000 * 60;
        var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);


        return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds < 9 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    }
    document.getElementById("tcresult").value = diff(start, end);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<td width="588"><p>IN 
  <input name="tcin" type="time" required class="fecha" id="tcin" form="ff"
                                                   step="1" title="Hora, minutos y segundos" value="09:59:59">
  <br>
  OUT
  <input name="tcout" type="time" required class="fecha" id="tcout" form="ff"
                                       title="Hora, minutos y segundos" step="1" value="10:00:00">
  <br>
  RESULT 
  <input name="tcresult" type="time" class="fecha" id="tcresult" form="ff"
                                       placeholder="00:00" title="Tiempo calculado" autocomplete="off" readonly>
</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read this out loud: `(hours < 9 ? "0" : "")` If Hours is less that nine. Is 9 less than 9?

Comment: Yeah, but it's just that 9 is necessary for me to do the math right. Any other options?

Comment: You are not thinking..... So why would 9 not get a zero? Elementary school math..... Is 9 < 9 ?

Comment: Try the `<=` (smaller or equal) operator...

Comment: I was missing the =, thanks Louys for the reply. I was not misguided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `<` (smaller) operator for `<=` (smaller or equal) about the leading zeros...

I also added a [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) condition to return an empty string if the caculation ends with a `NAN` (Not a Number).

Try it like this...

```js
window.onchange = function () {
  var start = document.getElementById("tcin").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("tcout").value;

  function diff(start, end) {
    start = start.split(":");
    end = end.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], start[2] ? start[2] : 0, 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], end[2] ? end[2] : 0, 0);

    //para que el cálculo funcione si la hora final se cruza al día siguiente. Por ejemplo. 11pm a 2am
    if (endDate.getTime() < startDate.getTime()) {
      endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
    diff -= minutes * 1000 * 60;
    var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

    if(!isNaN(hours) && !isNaN(minutes) && !isNaN(seconds)){
      return (hours <= 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds <= 9 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
    }else{
      return "";
    }

  }
  document.getElementById("tcresult").value = diff(start, end);
}
```

```html
in:<input id="tcin"><br>
out:<input id="tcout"><br>
result:<input id="tcresult"><br>
```

Comment: Now if that works perfect. A simple answer and making my fault see pedagogically and an extra with isnand